# PowerShell обрезает SSL сертификат при отправке через Invoke-RESTMethod

Tags: rest, ssl, powershell

Начал играться в [RestPS](https://github.com/jpsider/RestPS), при отправке ssl сертификата  с клиента на сервер, на сервере ловлю 401 ошибку, т.к. сертификат не приходит на сервер.
Вопрос, из-за чего PowerShell может отрезать SSL сертификат при использовании  Invoke-RESTMethod ?

Конструкция что я отправляю:

```
$RestMethodParams = @{
        Uri = 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint/shutdown'
        Method = 'Get'
        UseBasicParsing = $true
    }
Invoke-RestMethod @RestMethodParams
```

Конструкция которой я слушаю:

```
$ServerParams = @{
          RoutesFilePath = 'C:\RestPS\endpoints\RestPSRoutes.json'
          Port = 8080
          SSLThumbprint = $ServerCert.Thumbprint
          VerificationType = 'VerifyRootCA'
}
Start-RestPSListener @ServerParams
```

При проверке сертификата на сервере, получаю пустой вывод. Уже не знаю куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то будет интересно, невалдиный сертификат отрезается при отправке через invoke-RestMethod.
Сертификат должен содержать закрытый ключ. CA должен быть доверенным.